# How to check the existence of a node in .launch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm starting with launch files and I couldn't find any tutorial about it.
If you can share any paper, guide or explanatory website I would really appreciate it.

In addition, I want to put an "if" inside the launch file in order to create a node only IF it doesn't exits yet. ¿How can I do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172936/how-to-check-the-existence-of-a-node-in-.launch/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm starting with launch files and I couldn't find any tutorial about it.

Have you tried the [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) wiki page? The [Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch#Tutorials) section should help you get started.

> In addition, I want to put an "if" inside the launch file in order to create a node only IF it doesn't exits yet. ¿How can I do it?

Roslaunch cannot check for the (non)existence of a specific node. There is partial support for conditionals (`if` and `unless`), but it is used for conditional inclusion / evaluation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) for starting with launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1